# How to completely remove and start over with jenkins via docker?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I have been trying to learn docker and installing Jenkins using docker-compose. My compose file is listed below.  I also installed Jenkins locally on my mac to get familiar with it before dockerizing it, if that would interfere?  I remember in the installation process for Jenkins, I get prompted for an initial password and choosing modules, etc.   Whenever I completely remove all images, volumes and containers related to jenkins via docker, and perform a docker-compose up -d (following this tute: https://dev.to/andresfmoya/install-jenkins-using-docker-compose-4cab)   It automatically goes to a jenkins login screen (localhost:8081).  I've tried every login I can think of (don't know why I even  get to a login screen without setup), but also expected a setup process with going to this dir or similar to grab the initial password (cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword), but not sure why I'm not prompted like the initial install if I completely removed all jenkins related items via docker. I simply want to completely reset... What am I missing?

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
      - 50000:50000
    container_name: jenkins
    volumes:
      - ~/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker
```

Comment: It's probably saved credentials somewhere in `~/jenkins`. Try cleaning it before starting over.

Comment: @anemyte  that did it, thank you!